# How to refer to an int value inside a table in Lua? Is that even possible?

Tags: reference, lua

I want to refer to an integer, but the reference should be inside a table. The goal is an automatic string formatting function, which is updating the values every frame.

```
>> num = 5
>> table = {}
>> table[1] = num
>> num = 10
>> print(table[1])
>> 5
```

If i run this the value num is only getting copied, but i need a reference instead. 
I am writing a game with the lua löve2D library at the moment. Here is an excerpt of my code:

```
function StringDrawSystem:draw()
    for index, entity in pairs(self.targets) do
        local str = entity:getComponent("StringComponent")
        love.graphics.setFont(str.font)
        local position = entity:getComponent("PositionComponent")
        love.graphics.print(string.format(str.string, unpack(str.values)), position.x, position.y)
    end
end
```

`str.values` is a table that should contain the references to the wanted values. Those values are not necessarily global.

```
entity:getComponent("StringComponent") -- is equal to 
entity.components.StringComponent -- StringComponent is just 
                                  -- a component added to the entity
```

StringComponent is a simple class with 3 fields.

```
StringComponent = class("StringComponent")

function StringComponent:__init(font, string, values) 
    self.font = font
    self.string = string
    self.values = values
end
```

Comment: Any solution you come up with will have to involve using either tables or userdata because those are the only two types in lua that have any notion of mutable reference semantics.

Comment: Is `entity:getComponent` the function responsible for setting up `str.values`'s table?

Comment: You may be able to setup `str.values` so it triggers a `__index` and have the metamethod build up the table of values to return on-the-fly. But you still need to know where to get those values from -- probably do this via an upvalue like Colonel showed. I can give a more concrete example if you show how `str.values` is being setup.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution for my current problem. Every int i want to reference is in some kind of way a child of another table. So, for example, if you want to refer to `table.int` and `table2.int2` i pass `{{table, "int"}, {table2, "int2"}}` to `values` in the StringComponent's constructor. 
Now you are able to create a table with the updated values by using

```
local val = {}
for k, v in pairs(str.values) do
    table.insert(val, v[1][v[2]])
end
```

Now i am able to format the string with

```
string.format(str.string, unpack(val))
```

If you have a better solution, feel free to post it, so i can optimize my code.

Answer (score 2):

You can't do this directly, but you can instead provide a closure to call when you need the string value, like this:

```
x = 5
table = {}

table["key"] = function() return x end

print(table["key"]()) -- Will print 5
x = 10
print(table["key"]()) -- Will print 10
```

Comment: The main problem on this solution is that i would have to hardcode a function for every value i want to print. But the values i want to print are produced by different systems and the main engine that is managing my entitysystem. Those values are somewhere inside that engine and not predictable, but i can read them at certain points. At this points i want to put them inside the table to have a steady dynamically generated reference to print those values.

Comment: Then no, you can't do that. This isn't C. You should think about rethinking your approach if you are having to do this.

Comment: No, it won't print `10`!

Answer (score 2):

You can't do it without one more level of redirection, as you can't have references to numerics values. You can store the value you need in a table and modify the first element in that table:

```
num = {}
num[1] = 5
table = {}
table[1] = num
num[1] = 10
print(table[1][1])
-- 10
```

Comment: So i have to reference tables. Thanks for your advise.